# xpath expression to select and normalize-space

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I want to write an XPath expression that matches the `div` element with attribute`data-dmid="decimal-price-container"` and then normalizes the spaces between the text. I have written an XPath but does not work can someone also explain to me why it is not working `//div [contains(@data-dmid="decimal-price-container") and normalize-space(text())]`

```html
<div data-dmid="decimal-price-container" class="aci acj bt">
    <span data-dmid="price-digit" class="r t ack acl rn acm">4</span>
    <span data-dmid="price-cent" class="r t jk ack acl">95</span>
    <span data-dmid="price-currency" class="r t a jt jp acn jk">€</span>
</div>
```

Comment: between which text?  Please show your expected output.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It is a price and I want it to be something like this 495€ or anything near it would also work

Comment: You missed to define "`not working`" 

If we don't know what you really want to achieve (*maybe you yourself don't know*?) **then how can we be of any help**?

Answer (score 0):

By including the `normalize-space()` call within the predicate, you're attempting to select a `div` matching the `class` and having a non-white-space text node child.  There is no such node.

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(/div[@data-dmid="decimal-price-container"])
```

will return this string,

```
4 95 €
```

Comment: Thank but this expression is not working as I am using this for scraping. It is a screen scraper called octoparse. Is there any other XPath expression that I can use?

Comment: It works with XPath 1.0 conformant tools using your posted markup.  Whether your tool is non-conformant or your actual markup is different than you've posted, I could not tell you.  Only obvious change to try would be to use `//div` rather than `/div` as your targeted `div` is unlikely the root element as shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

**This XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
    "concat(//div[contains(concat(' ', @data-dmid, ' '), ' decimal-price-container ')]
                 /*[@data-dmid[. = 'price-digit']],
             '.',
             //div[contains(concat(' ', @data-dmid, ' '), ' decimal-price-container ')]
                 /*[@data-dmid[. = 'price-cent']],
             //div[contains(concat(' ', @data-dmid, ' '), ' decimal-price-container ')]
                 /*[@data-dmid[. = 'price-currency']]
             )
```

**when evaluated on the provided XML document**:

```xml
<div data-dmid="decimal-price-container" class="aci acj bt">
    <span data-dmid="price-digit" class="r t ack acl rn acm">4</span>
    <span data-dmid="price-cent" class="r t jk ack acl">95</span>
    <span data-dmid="price-currency" class="r t a jt jp acn jk">€</span>
</div>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

## `4.95€`

---

**XSLT- based verification**:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "concat(//div[contains(concat(' ', @data-dmid, ' '), ' decimal-price-container ')]
                 /*[@data-dmid[. = 'price-digit']],
             '.',
             //div[contains(concat(' ', @data-dmid, ' '), ' decimal-price-container ')]
                 /*[@data-dmid[. = 'price-cent']],
             //div[contains(concat(' ', @data-dmid, ' '), ' decimal-price-container ')]
                 /*[@data-dmid[. = 'price-currency']]
             )
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced.